# Submitting a form using ajax causes strange behavior with the Charset

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue here with a form being posted via Ajax.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#newdata").submit(function(event) {          
        event.preventDefault();          
        $.post( "save.asp",  $("#newdata").serialize() , 
          function( data ) {  
        });           
      });
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is when I submit data with special characters like `®` or `©` it saves it with an `Â` in front of it.  But if i submit without the jQuery/Ajax it doesn't format the data with this `Â` character.  Does anyone know why I'm having this problem?

Comment: I think its an issue with character encoding. Try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
` 
Or

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
`

Or even `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Comment: By default JQuery is sending it to the server using UTF-8.  The problem is the data is being encoded using the `serialize` method and is not being decoded on the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aTS67/2/

The problem is with the `.serialize()` method (it is not really a problem, it should do this).  As you can see from my demo above when you use the method it encodes the special characters (as it should).  You have two options:

1. Decode the url-encoded string on the server-side.  You didn't mention what technology you are using but their is likely a function that will do this for you. For PHP for instance you may use `htmlspecialchars_decode("YOUR ENCODED STRING");` but there will be something similiar for all server-side languages (best option)
2. Instead of using `.serialize()` you can build the string sent to the server-side manually.  You can replace `$("#newdata").serialize()` with an object literal of key value pairs:

`{"InputId1" : $("#InputId1").val(), "InputId2" : $("#InputId2").val()}`

**Edit**

Just saw the extension on your file is ASP so you are using classic asp.  I am not sure what the syntax is to decode but I am sure it is easy to find.

Comment: You solution is accurate, but I provided specific details on why this is happening in my answer.  It needs to have the proper codepage set.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone else has this problem, the resolution is to have `<%@codepage=65001%>` at the top of the receiving page. jquery.serialize() serializes using utf8 and this basically puts the receiving page in the correct codepage.

**NOTE: This is for classic asp.**

Source: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/